Spring boot 3 en Payara 6
necesito algo de ayuda para saber cómo desplegar una aplicación de Spring Boot 3 en un servidor de Payara 6, cree la carpeta WEB-INF y puse el web.xml y el beans.xml bajo las definiciones de Jakarta 10, pero me dice que es incapaz de cargar el Bean de EntityManager de Jakarta, ¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar eso? No consigo información

Al final resulta ser que era un problema con el CDI de Payara y el "CDI" personalizado que usa Spring Boot, solo tuve que crear un archivo en esta ruta: webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml, webapp está al mismo nivel que resources, y ese archivo debe estar completamente vacío para que funcione (yo lo había llenado con su formato estándar)
Al llenar beans.xml, hacía que el servidor hiciera búsqueda de ciertos beans como entitymanager que aún no habían sido cargados, causando el conflicto
